# Multiple file upload with Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to upload multiple images.

My form is this:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" name="images[]">
  <input type="file" name="images[]">
  <input type="file" name="images[]">
</form>
```

I know that this form is right. I am getting an error when Codeigniter tries to upload a file.

```
function do_upload_images() {
    $files = $_FILES;

    $cpt = count ( $_FILES ['images'] ['name'] );
    for($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i ++) {

        $_FILES ['images'] ['name'] = $files ['images'] ['name'] [$i];
        $_FILES ['images'] ['type'] = $files ['images'] ['type'] [$i];
        $_FILES ['images'] ['tmp_name'] = $files ['images'] ['tmp_name'] [$i];
        $_FILES ['images'] ['error'] = $files ['images'] ['error'] [$i];
        $_FILES ['images'] ['size'] = $files ['images'] ['size'] [$i];

        $this->upload->initialize ( $this->set_upload_options () );
        $this->upload->do_upload ($_FILES['images']);
    }
}
private function set_upload_options() {
    // upload an image options
    $config = array ();
    $config ['upload_path'] = './uploads/estate_images';
    $config ['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config ['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

    return $config;
}
```

This is the error i got:

> Message: Illegal offset type in isset or empty Filename:
>   libraries/Upload.php Line Number: 377

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615489/i-cant-upload-multiple-file-upload-in-codeignitor

Comment: As we can return an array of data, all information files uploads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get the solution by myself. Just needed to change the following line:

```
$this->upload->do_upload ($_FILES['images']);
```

to

```
$this->upload->do_upload ('images');
```

Comment: Is it really working ?! do_upload() seems expecting string not an array ?!

Comment: As we can return an array of data, all information files uploads?